# Finding subnet mask on Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, networking, subnet

I am interested in finding the subnet mask of the local host programatically in Linux preferably through the native C api.

Comment: You must take into account that there may be multiple network interfaces in a host.

Answer (score 8):

[getifaddrs()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) will give you a list of your network interfaces and the field `ifa_netmask` should be the mask for each.

Comment: Or a corresponding `ioctl` (http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl_list.2.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `ifconfig` utility uses `ioctl()` with the `SIOCGIFNETMASK` command to get the netmask.  But I think Duck's answer is more user-friendly.